# I need to modify an existing query to return records created after a certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server-express

I have the following query to return all Item Codes ever created which works just fine.

```
SELECT 
    ITM_CD, ITM_NAME, ITM_GROUP_NAME,
    ITM_ATTR01_DESC, ITM_ATTR02_DESC, ITM_ATTR03_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR04_DESC, ITM_ATTR05_DESC, ITM_ATTR06_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR07_DESC, ITM_ATTR08_DESC, ITM_ATTR09_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR10_DESC, ITM_ATTR11_DESC, ITM_ATTR12_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR13_DESC, ITM_ATTR14_DESC, BSP_SELL_PRICE,
    BCP_COST_PRICE, VEN_VENDOR_NAME 
FROM 
    ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 
    BASIC_SP_MST,
    BASIC_CP_MST,
    VENDOR_MST 
WHERE 
    ITM_STATUS='O'AND 
    BSP_ORG_CD='001'AND 
    ITM_CD=BSP_ITEM_CD AND 
    ITM_CD=BCP_VEND_ITEM_CD AND 
    BCP_VEND_CD=VEN_VENDOR_CD AND 
    BCP_ORG_cD='001'
```

However, I want to see the Item Codes created after a specific date, for eg. 16 March 2012.

for that I tried

```
SELECT 
    ITM_CD, ITM_NAME, ITM_GROUP_NAME,
    ITM_ATTR01_DESC, ITM_ATTR02_DESC, ITM_ATTR03_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR04_DESC, ITM_ATTR05_DESC, ITM_ATTR06_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR07_DESC, ITM_ATTR08_DESC, ITM_ATTR09_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR10_DESC, ITM_ATTR11_DESC, ITM_ATTR12_DESC,
    ITM_ATTR13_DESC, ITM_ATTR14_DESC, BSP_SELL_PRICE,
    BCP_COST_PRICE, VEN_VENDOR_NAME 
FROM 
    ITEM_DESCRIPTION, 
    BASIC_SP_MST,
    BASIC_CP_MST,
    VENDOR_MST 
WHERE 
    ITM_STATUS='O'AND 
    BSP_ORG_CD='001'AND 
    ITM_CD=BSP_ITEM_CD AND 
    ITM_CD=BCP_VEND_ITEM_CD AND 
    BCP_VEND_CD=VEN_VENDOR_CD AND 
    BCP_ORG_cD='001' AND 
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE > '16-MARCH-2012'
```

But got the error

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Ambiguous column name 'LAST_UPDATED_DATE'.

What am I doing wrong and what can i do to correct it.

I am using MS SQL Server Management Studio Express

As you can see, I am not even a novice, hence thanks for bearing with me.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
RItin

Comment: Do you have this column LAST_UPDATED_DATE  in more than one table? If that is the case specify the name of the table you want to use like: table.LAST_UPDATED_DATE 

PS. My comment is more like an answer, rather than comment.

Comment: @animatora, why don't you add it as an answer instead ;)

Comment: @Gaby My bad, I didn't pay attention to where I was typing in.

Answer (score 4):

That means that `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` is a column name in 2 tables and the SQL Engine does not know which one to take.

You can tell the engine by adding the table name like that:

```
table_name.LAST_UPDATED_DATE
```

Your query:

```
SELECT ITM_CD,
   ITM_NAME,
   ITM_GROUP_NAME,
   ITM_ATTR01_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR02_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR03_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR04_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR05_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR06_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR07_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR08_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR09_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR10_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR11_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR12_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR13_DESC,
   ITM_ATTR14_DESC,
   BSP_SELL_PRICE,
   BCP_COST_PRICE,
   VEN_VENDOR_NAME 
FROM ITEM_DESCRIPTION,BASIC_SP_MST,BASIC_CP_MST,VENDOR_MST 
WHERE ITM_STATUS='O'
  AND BSP_ORG_CD='001'
  AND ITM_CD=BSP_ITEM_CD 
  AND ITM_CD=BCP_VEND_ITEM_CD 
  AND BCP_VEND_CD=VEN_VENDOR_CD 
  AND BCP_ORG_cD='001' 
  AND tablename.LAST_UPDATED_DATE > '16-MARCH-2012'  <-- here is a table name needed for LAST_UPDATED_DATE
```

Update:
By the way I think using the string `16-MARCH-2012` won't work. Try `16-03-2012` instead for date comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The message means that more than one table you selecting data from contains column LAST_UPDATED_DATE. Add prefix before column name

Answer (score 0):

It happens when a column with same name is present in more than one one table....As from your scenario,'LAST_UPDATED_DATE' seems to present in more than one table.....Thus,specify the table name along with column name.........

```
table_name.LAST_UPDATED_DATE
```